# spock test for a service in grails

Tags: grails, spock

I have a service in my application which return a list of tracks, here is the code for that

```
List<Track> getTrackListTracks(String listName, int max) {
    def tracks = getTrackListTracks(listName)
    if(tracks?.size() > max) {
        tracks = tracks[0 ..< max]
    }
    return tracks
}

List<Track> getTrackListTracks(String listName) {
    def tl = TrackList.findByName(listName)
    if(tl?.tracks) {
        return tl?.tracks?.collect { Track.read(it.trackId) }
    }
}
```

i have to write the unit test for this but I am not able to write. Can anyone help me in this.
Thanks Already

Comment: def 'test getTrackListTracks method with two parameter returns correct value'() {

        expect:
            
           trackListService.getTrackListTracks(listName, max) == tracks
       
        where:
            listName | max | tracks  
             'homepage-tracks' | 5 | ['com.supajam.domain.Track' : '2328', 'com.supajam.domain.Track' : '2323', 'com.supajam.domain.Track' : '799', 'com.supajam.domain.Track' : '1281', 'com.supajam.domain.Track' : '1490']
    }
I have written this code but it is not working as the service is returning a list of tracks, so not able compare them

Comment: @vivek please put the test code into your question. It is very unreadable in comment.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully you've progressed beyond this, but for those coming after, the grails-spock-examples project @ google code (https://github.com/pschneider-manzell/grails-spock-examples) has a wide range of examples.

More specifically, for a service (as you've asked), check out [Testing Services](https://github.com/pschneider-manzell/grails-spock-examples/wiki).

Caution, though - there are a few differences between that and what is required for Grails 2.  For example, if testing controllers, 'redirectArgs' is no longer valid.  Make sure to also consult the [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html) for differences.